# Pagination in Clean Architecture with CQRS // C#

Tags: c#, pagination, clean-architecture

For few weeks I've been learning Clean Architecture with CQRS. I've got a question about good practices and how to implement something better to make code more performant.

Question concerns pagination and how to implement it well. As I understand the best way is to paginate result during fetching from DB to not get all records from DB and then start paginating on UI layer.

I've put PaginatedList(pagenumber, totalpages, List etc.) and RequestParams classes in Application Layer. My handler looks like this:

```
public async Task < PaginatedList < TransactionInListViewModel >> Handle(GetTransactionsByBudgetIdQuery request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var userId = _userService.GetUserId;
    var transactions = await _transactionRepository.GetTransactionsByBudgetIdAsync(
        userId,
        request.BudgetId,
        request.PageNumber,
        request.PageSize);

    var transactionDto = _mapper.Map < List < TransactionInListViewModel >> (transactions.Items);

    var result = new PaginatedList < TransactionInListViewModel > (
        transactionDto,
        transactions.TotalCount,
        transactions.PageNumber,
        transactions.PageSize);

    return result;
}
```

Method asks repository for record created by user himself, from specific basket with pagination parameters.

In repository I had simple request to db with those parameters and repository returned Transaction List (IEnumerable).

Then this handler had to map the record and return paginated result. Here started the problem, everything looked perfect until I realized that parameters like TotalCount and everything connected to it (like HasPreviousePage HasNextPage) behave like I only have asked about one page and thats all - TotalCount was the amount of PageSize, and except PageNumber and PageSize the rest just show false results :)

I was trying to find the solution and I found it, but I dont know if it still follows Clean Architecture rules or I just started messing everything up. I refactored Repository class in Infrastructure layer to this:

```
public async Task < PaginatedList < Transaction >> GetTransactionsByBudgetIdAsync(int userId, int budgetId, int pageNumber, int pageSize) {

    var baseQuery = await _dbContext
        .Transactions
        .Where(t => t.CreatedById == userId)
        .Where(t => t.BudgetId == budgetId)
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate)
        .ToListAsync();

    var count = baseQuery.Count();

    var transactions = baseQuery
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();

    return new PaginatedList < Transaction > (transactions, count, pageNumber, pageSize);

}
```

As I said, now whole results looks fine, but for me it looks messy and I dont think It follows CA rules. If I have PaginatedList class in Application Layer should I use it in TransactionRepository (which is in Infrastructure layer) to return PaginatedResult with perfectly counted numbers and then Map the result in Handler and Paginate it again?

Thanks for all responses!

Comment: The other method I could use is to fetch from Repository whole records fit to parameters userId and budgetId return it as a IEnumerable and then paginate it in Handler in Application Layer. This works fine, but if there would be thousands of records it could affect on performance badly.

Comment: For dto results (ui queries) don't go from repository. Instead in your application layer call directly db get what you want, map to dto and return what ever ui screen needs. Either paginated results with total count and total pages or simple dto list. Using repository, at the beginning it might looks it's working but as far you go you realize that you need to modify your repository to match ui which is wrong. Repositories should be only for crud domain models and or basic queries that make sense in your domain context.